# Three Chords Forming Triangle in Circle

Tags: geometry

If we know have a triangle whose three vertices (whose angles are known) are three points on a circle, and so each side length of the triangle is a chord, can we find the length of each side, assuming we know the radius of the circle?

Answer (score 1):

Without the angles no, because every (nondegenerate) triangle has a circumcircle: circle passing through the three vertices of the triangle.

In other words, knowing the radius of the circumcircle does not identify the ratio of the sides or the area of the triangle.

---

If you know all three angles in the triangle, you can arbitrarily choose one of the sides to be of unit length ($1$), and solve the two other sides based on that one side and the three known angles.  Just be careful which side is which (i.e., that side $a$ is opposite known angle $A$, and so on).

(Personally, I always choose the side opposite the smallest angle to be $1$, as then the other two are larger.  If it then looks like one of the other sides is shorter, I know I made an error somewhere – this helps me catch (some of) my mistakes.)

Then, calculate the [circumradius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumcircle) of the circumscribed circle for this triangle.  If the side lengths are $a$, $b$, and $c$, and the triangle perimeter $p = a + b + c$, then the [circumradius of the circle is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Circumradius_and_inradius) $R$,
$$R = \sqrt{\frac{a^2 b^2 c^2}{(a + b + c)(-a + b + c)(a - b + c)(a + b - c)}}$$
Because the shape of the triangle is now known, you only need to scale it.

If the original triangle circumradius is $R^\prime$, scale the side lengths by $\frac{R^\prime}{R}$ to find the actual side lengths of the original triangle.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question, what if we know all 3 angles?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Given a circle of radius r, there are many different triangles with many different side lengths.  There are some special cases.  An equilateral has each angle 60 degrees.  Drawing the radii to two or the vertices we get a triangle with two sides of length r and angle between them 120 degrees.  The third side of that triangle, one side of the equilateral triangle, satisfies the cosine law: s^2= r^2(1- cos(120))= 3r^2/2.  s= (sqrt(3/2)r.

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the question. What if we know all 3 angles?